# How to extract numerical values after expression '\xb' in byte string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, utf-8, byte

I am attempting to extract numerical values from a byte string transmitted from an RS-232 port. Here is an example:

`b'S\xa0S\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xb23.6\xb7\xa0\xe7\x8d\n'`

If I attempt to decode the byte string as 'utf-8', I receive the following output:

```
x = b'S\xa0S\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xb23.6\xb7\xa0\xe7\x8d\n'
x.decode('utf-8', errors='ignore')

>>> 'SS3.6\n'
```

What I ideally want is 23.67, which is observed after every `\xb` pattern. How could I extract 23.67 from this byte string?

Comment: If you just want to extract the number, you don't need to decode the string and you can just use a regex match, e.g.: `re.findall('\d+.[\d]+', str(x))`

Comment: Who are sending these bytes?
Is there a protocol?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to get 23.67 from that byte string try this:

```
a = b'S\xa0S\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xb23.6\xb7\xa0\xe7\x8d\n'
b = repr(a)[2:-1]
c = b.split("\\")
d = ''
e = []
for i in c:
    if "xb" in i:
        e.append(i[2:])
d = "".join(e)
print(d)
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/59416410/3319460, your input actually doesn't really represent the output you seek. But just to fulfil your requirements, of course, we might set semantics onto the input such that

- numbers or `'.'` sign is allowed, others are skipped
- if the byte is non-ASCII character such whether the first four bytes are `0xB`. If it is the case then we will simply take the ASCII part of the byte (`b & 0b01111111`)

That is quite easily done in Python.

```
def _filter(char):
    return char & 0xF0 == 0xB0 or chr(char) == "." or 48 <= char <= 58


def filter_xbchars(value: bytes) -> str:
    return "".join(chr(ch & 0b01111111) for ch in value if _filter(ch))


import pytest


@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "value, expected",
    [(b"S\xa0S\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xb23.6\xb7\xa0\xe7\x8d\n", "23.67")],
)
def test_simple(value, expected):
    assert filter_xbchars(value) == expected
```

**Please be aware** that even though code above satisfies the *requirements* it is an example of a poorly described task and as a result quite nonsensical solution. The code solves the task as you asked for it but we should firstly reconsider whether it even makes sense. I advise you to check the data you will test against and the meaning of the data (protocol).

Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

Please notice that `\xHH` is an escape code representing hexadecimal value `HH` and as such your string `'\xb23.6\xb7'` does not contain `"23.67"` but rater `"(0xB2)3.6(0xB7)"`, those value cannot be extracted using a regular expression because it's not present in the string in the first place.

`'\xb23.6\xb7'` is not a valid UTF-8 sequence, and in [Latin-1 extended ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) it would represent `"²3.6·"`; the presence of many `0xA0` values would suggest a Latin-1 encoding as it represent a non-breaking space in that encoding (a fairly common character) while in UTF-8 it does not encode a meaningful sequence.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I wonder how I can return a non hexadecimal value. Using macOS, I am having this trouble. On raspberry pi, this is not an issue - for example, \xa0 is represented as a blank space.